# Pass value between tabs on onClick event in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the component I am working on. I have three tab named newOrder, currentOrder and orderHistory.

How can I move a card in New Order tab, to Current Order tab when I press 'Accept' button on card.

```
export default class Driver extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      key: 'home',
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Tabs id="controlled-tab-example" activeKey={this.state.key} 
       onSelect{key => this.setState({ key })}>
       <Tab eventKey="newOrder" title="New Order">
        //this is the card with Accept button.
         <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">          
            <Button type="button>Accept</Button>                     
            </div>
         </div>   
        </Tab>

        <Tab eventKey="currentOrder" title="Current Order"></Tab>

        <Tab eventKey="orderHistory" title="OrderHistory"></Tab>
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using the component state. You may refer this link: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html